# Oracle Trigger Replace

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

We have cloned a schema "old_schema_name" to a new schema with name "new_schema_name". But due to triggers (and procedures) referencing old schema name we had to drop triggers to not have the old schema effected.
For example: we have following trigger (which is dropped) on Schema "New_schema_name" , we want to update this trigger so that it does not reference "old_schema_name".

Is just adding Trigger (via Create or replace trigger) enough for this trigger to be activated ?

```
DROP TRIGGER NEW_SCHEMA_NAME.TRG_UPDATE_SOMETHING;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NEW_SCHEMA_NAME.TRG_UPDATE_SOMETHING
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON OLD_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_CONFIG REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DISABLE
DECLARE
tmpVar NUMBER;

BEGIN
tmpVar := 0;
SELECT someseq.nextval INTO tmpVar FROM dual;
UPDATE UPDATE_VERSION SET counter = tmpVar, upd_time= sysdate WHERE id =      'SomeID';   
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END TRG_UPDATE_SOMETHING;
```

Comment: Do you really want `ON OLD_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_CONFIG` or want it  as `ON NEW_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_CONFIG`?

Comment: How did you clone it? If you use datapump export/import you can change the schema name (in most places anyway) via a remap option. Probably a bit late now... Just to clarify, whatever you did created the triggers in the new schema, but using DDL that had the old schema name hard-coded in for the table references?

Comment: Gurwinder  I need NEW_SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_CONFIG . Alex  I really do not procedure to clone, it was done by our db admins, but seems old schemas name were hardcoded in table references in some of the triggers and procedures, and i think there is no check on these on clone process.